# Is there a way to be notified when mail moves to a folder in Notes?

Tags: directory, lotusscript, agent, ibm-domino, hcl-notes

We have another program that connects to our mail file through IMAP and moves documents to either a processed or "Errors" folder.  Can I create an agent to notify us if a document is moved to the Errors folder?  We are using Domino 9.0.1 FP 8.  I was looking to see if this could be done through Lotuscript, but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no (backend) event when a document is put in a folder. The only possibility is a scheduled agent (every 5 minutes is the minimum interval) to check, if something changed.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I'm still struggling with how this could be done.  Could you provide a bit of an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create an agent. But you could use a combination of the Notes C API Extension Manager and an agent. The Extension Manager can hook an event called EM_NSFADDTOFOLDER. You could just write whatever code you need to react to that in C, but you don't have to. To make this a lot easier, there's [an opensource project called Trigger Happy on the OpenNTF site](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy) which provides what you need for the Extension Manager part and it invokes an agent for you when the event fires on the server.  Of course, you'll need admin help to get this deployed.